# what does nil mean/represent here?

Tags: ruby, null

Following are the simple statements in the `irb` shell. What does `nil`in the output mean ? Why does it accompany the print statement in the `if` block ?

```
irb(main):062:0> if(x==20 && y==30)
irb(main):063:1> print("if statement working !")
irb(main):064:1> else
irb(main):065:1* print("else statement working !!")
irb(main):066:1> end
if statement working !=> nil # what does nil represent here ?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Ruby, all expressions return values, even if it's `nil`. Blocks and methods simply return the value of the last expression evaluated. There are many ways to use this effectively. For example, this is the reason explicit `return`s are often not used. Also, you can do this:

```
print if x == 20 && y == 30
  'if statement working!'
else
  'else statement working!'
end
```

Regarding your example: in addition to printing the string as you instructed, `irb` will display the value it received from the if-else blocks. Since [`print`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-print) always returns `nil`, both branches will return the same value.

Answer (score 2):

It means that your if-block does not return a value (which it can, actually). For instance, the following is perfectly legal and viable:

```
foo = if bar > 10
    42
else
    0
end

# now, foo is either 42 or 0
```

Comment: In other words , print/puts do not return a value.

Comment: `nil` __is__ a value; it is an instance of [`NilClass`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/NilClass.html) and responds to methods like any other object.

Comment: While that is technically correct, I don't think that is what the OP was primarily interested in.